# How do I convert Months from Numeral to String Form in SQL Query Containing GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date, sql-date-functions

So, I'm creating a View that pulls a bunch of data (with a SUM aggregate on one field). The query contains GROUP BY clause and when I do the month conversion in the query as follows, I get an %invalid character% error.

```
SELECT Code, Name, Products, SUM(Costs) AS TOTAL, 
Year, to_char(to_date(PurchaseMonth),'DD-Mon-yyyy') AS MonthProductPurchased
FROM ProductCatalog
<BUNCH OF JOINS HERE>
WHERE ABC.Code=DEF.Code AND Products IS NOT null
GROUP BY Code, Name, Products, Year, MonthProductPurchased;
```

So, for instance, I want to convert '1' in the Month field to 'January', '2' to February, so on and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see, you have something called `PurchaseMonth` and it takes the values 1, 2, 3, etc.  You want to convert these to month names.  How about this?

```
to_char(to_date('2000-' || PurchaseMonth || '-01'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MONTH')
```

Comment: So, in my Group By clause, I'll include PurchaseMonth, correct?

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I get yellow squiggly lines in my SELECT statement with a tip saying to include to_char(to_date('2000-' || PurchaseMonth || '-01'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MONTH') in the GROUP BY clause. I tried the alias and it doesn't accept it. What do I put in my Group By clause for the error to go away?

Comment: @user2425909 . . . Put the entire expression in the `group by`, or just `PurchaseMonth`.

Comment: It worked. It shows the yellow squiggly lines in SQL Developer still but the query works perfectly the way you stated. Thanks, man.

Comment: `to_char(to_date(PurchaseMonth, 'MM'), 'MONTH')` [would be enough](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/35975)!

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar . . . partial dates make me nervous.